# Name for property $\vec{a}\cdot f(\vec{x}) \le \vec{b}\cdot f(\vec{x})$ whenever $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x} \le \vec{b}\cdot\vec{x}$?

Tags: inequality, vectors, convex-analysis, inner-products

This question has probably been asked before, but I don't know how to phrase the property in English so as to use the right search terms to find it on Google. If this question is a duplicate, please feel free to close this question and link to the original.

For any $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$, and any $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, let $f(\vec{x}):=(f(x_1), \dots, f(x_n))$. The question is:

> What is the name of the following property for a function $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$? For any $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, for any $\vec{a},\vec{b} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\vec{a}\cdot\vec{x} \le \vec{b}\cdot\vec{x}$, one has that $\vec{a}\cdot f(\vec{x}) \le \vec{b} \cdot f(\vec{x})$.

**Attempt:** I think it might be related to convexity, since a function $f$ is convex if and only if for any $\vec{c} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ whose entries are non-negative and sum to $1$, for any $\vec{x} \le \mathbb{R}^n$, $f(\vec{c}\cdot \vec{x}) \le \vec{c} \cdot f(\vec{x})$. If in addition $f$ is non-decreasing, that implies $\vec{c}\cdot \vec{x} \le \vec{c} \cdot f(\vec{x})$. Then for any $\vec{v} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ whose entries are non-negative, since $(\vec{v}/||\vec{v}||_1) \cdot \vec{x} \le (\vec{v}/||\vec{v}||_1)\le f(\vec{x})$, one also has $\vec{v} \cdot \vec{x} \le \vec{v} \cdot f(\vec{x})$.

However that wouldn't extend to vectors with any negative entries, whereas $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ can be arbitrary. And in any case the goal is to compare $\vec{a} \cdot f(\vec{x})$ and $\vec{b} \cdot f(\vec{x})$, not $\vec{a} \cdot f(\vec{x})$ and $\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x}$.

Obviously $f:x \mapsto x$ satisfies the property.

> Are there any other functions satisfying the property?

Comment: I'm confused by your definition of convexity, does $f$ take vectors or scalars there?

Comment: $f(\vec{x}) = g(\vec{x}) \vec{x}$ works where $g: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$

Comment: @StephenDonovan Good question, $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, so if there are any places where it takes a vector as "input", it's either shorthand for applying $f$ entrywise, or should be applied to a dot product reducing a vector to a scalar -- there might have been typos.

Comment: @TomKern Would you elaborate on the proof in an answer? I'd be happy to accept it. Are there additional conditions on $g$, e.g. being non-decreasing? For example, thinking about $g: \mathbb{R}\setminus \{0 \} \to \mathbb{R}^{\ge 0}$ where $g(x) = | 1 /x|$, $\vec{a}=(1, -\frac{1}{2})$, $\vec{b}=(3,\frac{1}{2})$, $\vec{x}=(\frac{1}{2}, -2)$ (so $g(\vec{x}) = (1,-1)$) does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any function $f$ provided $f(\vec{x})$ is always pointing in the same direction as $\vec{x}$.

Specifically, if $g : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{\geq 0}$, then $f(\vec{x}) = g(\vec{x}) \vec{x}$ works. Specifically, $g$ associates a nonnegative scalar to every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

In particular,

$$\vec{a} \cdot \vec{x} \leq \vec{b} \cdot \vec{x}$$

Multiply both sides by $g(\vec{x})$:

$$g(\vec{x}) \vec{a} \cdot \vec{x} \leq g(\vec{x})\vec{b} \cdot \vec{x}$$

Scalar multiple property of dot products:

$$\vec{a} \cdot (g(\vec{x})\vec{x}) \leq \vec{b} \cdot (g(\vec{x})\vec{x})$$

By the definition of $f$:

$$\vec{a} \cdot f(\vec{x}) \leq \vec{b} \cdot f(\vec{x})$$

In fact, this is all such functions. Suppose that we have such an $f$ and $\vec{x}$. By the $\cos$ definition of the dot product:

$$f(\vec{x}) \cdot \vec{x} \leq \left(\frac{\vec{x} |f(\vec{x})|}{|\vec{x}|}\right) \cdot \vec{x}$$

(The left side is just the right side times $\cos(\theta)$ where $\theta$ is the angle between $\vec{x}$ and $f(\vec{x})$.)

Applying the property of $f$ with $\vec{a} = f(\vec{x})$ and $\vec{b} = \left(\frac{\vec{x} |f(\vec{x})|}{|\vec{x}|}\right)$:

$$f(\vec{x}) \cdot f(\vec{x}) \leq \frac{|f(\vec{x})|}{|\vec{x}|} \vec{x} \cdot f(\vec{x})$$

The left side is $|f(\vec{x})|^2$ and the right side is $|f(\vec{x})|^2 \cos(\theta)$, so $\theta$ must be $0$.

Comment: Ooh wow this is really nice, especially the proof of necessity is really beautiful imo. Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.